# Dualboot Windows 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have Ubuntu installed and, I want Windows 7 also.
(I don't have any backups of Windows from when I installed Ubuntu, I have an HP deskop, also I want to boot via USB.)

Comment: Or Windows 8 doesn't mater. (PC came with Windows 8)

Comment: Do backups. Wait, let me say it in another way: **why you don't have backups??**

Answer (score 0):

If you need Windows only to run some apps, not games you can use VirtualBox and save your virtual disk on drive - I use this method and it's cool in such a situation.

Installing Windows next to Ubuntu is worth when you want to play games, or use demanding programs. 
The most annoying thing here is other file system in Ubuntu - ext4 and NTFS in Windows. Linux can see Windows files, but from 7 Ubuntu files won't be visible. In the past I made partition in NTFS and put all my datas there. I had to add its to mounting list /etc/fstab but it's easy. If you like my solution you need also third partition for Windows OS, but as well you can put all the data there.

With GParted you will able to create partitions. Grub will add both systems by himself.